# Python Selenium, check if <div ...> contains a word in web-scraping code

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I am running a scraper using Selenium and BeautifulSoup and I want to check whether a certain word is in <div...>.

A snippet of the HTML code is as follows:

```
<div data-asin="0974158232" data-index="0" data-uuid="1f362f6b-dde2-4377-a5f3-518513486b7d" data-component-type="s-search-result" class="s-result-item s-asin sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-12-of-16" data-component-id="14" data-cel-widget="search_result_0"><div class="sg-col-inner">
<div data-asin="" data-index="1" class="a-section a-spacing-none s-result-item s-flex-full-width s-border-bottom-none s-widget" data-cel-widget="search_result_1">
<div data-asin="" data-index="2" class="a-section a-spacing-none s-result-item s-flex-full-width s-border-bottom-none s-widget" data-cel-widget="search_result_2">
```

I would like, first of all, to check if `div data-asin=""` is empty or if there is a string as in `data-asin="0974158232"`.

If it is empty I would like to enter in the <div...> and look for the `data-asin`. An example from `div data-asin="" data-index="2"` is:

```
> <div data-asin="" data-index="2" class="a-section a-spacing-none s-result-item s-flex-full-width s-border-bottom-none s-widget" data-cel-widget="search_result_2">
> <span cel_widget_id="MAIN-SEARCH_RESULTS-2" class="celwidget slot=MAIN template=SEARCH_RESULTS 
  widgetId=fkmr-search-results" data-csa-c-id="9so6vg-imque6-h59746-o5az71" data-cel-widget="MAIN- 
  SEARCH_RESULTS-2">
    > <div class="s-result-list sg-row">
       > <div class="s-result-item sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-8-of-12 sg-col-12-of-16" data-cel- 
         widget="search_result_3">
       > <div data-asin="0974158216" data-index="0" data-uuid="99a1b582-2fcb-49b8-8d13-739783e460a5" 
         data-component-type="s-search-result" class="s-result-item s-asin sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-16- 
         of-20 sg-col sg-col-12-of-16" data-component-id="15" data-cel-widget="search_result_4"><div 
         class="sg-col-inner">
       > <div data-asin="1433692163" data-index="1" data-uuid="8f8bfb8c-6083-4c26-bdd5-3032bcfe4bed" 
         data-component-type="s-search-result" class="s-result-item s-asin sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-16- 
         of-20 sg-col sg-col-12-of-16" data-component-id="16" data-cel-widget="search_result_5">
```

Here, I would like to tell the code to look for `data-asin=""` and check if it is an empty string or not. In this case it would not be empty because we have: `<div data-asin="0974158216"` and `<div data-asin="1433692163"`

I was thinking to use a for-loop or try/except, but I am very new with Selenium and HTML and I do not know how to approach this problem. Any kind of help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you share URL? Can you use `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely sure,thanks for the reply! the URL is [link](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=A+Biblically+Based+Model+of+Cultural+Competence+in+the+Delivery+of+Healthcare+Services:+Seeing&ref=nb_sb_noss) 
I have import beautiful soup yes. Have never used it much but it'd be great to learn something so please go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search `<div>` with non-empty `data-asin="..."`, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=A+Biblically+Based+Model+of+Cultural+Competence+in+the+Delivery+of+Healthcare+Services%3A+Seeing&ref=nb_sb_noss"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

# search only data-asin that have value, print it and the title
for div in soup.find_all("div", {"data-asin": bool}):
    print(div["data-asin"], div.select_one(".a-text-normal").text)
```

Prints:

```
0974158232 A Biblically Based Model of Cultural Competence in the Delivery of Healthcare Services: Seeing 
1433692163 Planting Missional Churches: Your Guide to Starting Churches that Multiply 
0310341728 Less Than Perfect: Broken Men and Women of the Bible and What We Can Learn from Them 
0800796853 God's Smuggler 
1885904088 The Excellent Wife: A Biblical Perspective 
B07K7YJPXD Hope Channel 
B07F1DNGMS Alistair Begg - Truth For Life 
B07DHZ6DL9 Star Trek Beyond (4K UHD) 
B0010ZONIY Heart of the Ukulele
```

Comment: Thank you @AndrejKesely ! I will test it shortly but looks promising. Could I ask you to elaborate a bit on two things please?
1) I have to run the code through a high number of products hence  doing it with the URL seems impossible. Would `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)` do the trick?
2) could explain what this `{"data-asin": bool}` does?

Comment: @econnoob5 1.) You need to load the page somehow and then "feed" the HTML source to beautifulsoup. You can do it with `requests` or `selenium`.  2.) `{"data-asin": bool}` select all elements with `data-asin=` property, where the `bool(<value of data-asin property>)` evaluates to `True`. So it will filter-out empty attributes (`""`)

Comment: Thank you, very clear @AndrejKesely . What I am struggling with is that I do not have a list of URLs. I have a list of products that I am typing in the Amazon search box, but then at this point I do not know how to get the URL to feed the HTML source to beautifulsoup. Would you have any ideas on how to do this? it seems like requests could do the trick but I am not sure how

Comment: @econnoob5 You can try to change the `k` parameter in the URL to search for new products.